# Javascript for loop firebase update

Tags: javascript, php, firebase

I have a news feed, using Firebase, and would like to be able to "check" all of the news items as read with one click.

HTML:

```
<ul id="news" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li id="newsitem_read">Mark all as read</li>
    <li id="-K230_cSX_TOYlXfSjul" class="newsitem unread-true">message</li>
    <li id="-K247s6SLY4AGliAUIik" class="newsitem unread-true">message</li>
    <li id="-K24820ZIQR8LqThIRFb" class="newsitem unread-true">message</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var news = greatnonsens.child('users/<?=$_SESSION['user']['id']; ?>/news_feed/');

var read = document.getElementById('newsitem_read');

read.addEventListener('click', function() {

    var to_read = document.getElementsByClassName('unread-true');

    // Check news feed is not empty
    if (typeof to_read[0] !== 'undefined') {
        for (var i = 0; i < to_read.length; i++) { 
            news.child(to_read[i].id).update({unread: 'false'});
            // document.getElementById(to_read[i].id).className = 'newsitem unread-false';
            console.log(to_read[i].id);
        }
    }   
});
```

This is working, but if I also run document.getElementById(to_read[i].id).className = 'newsitem unread-false' it only updates every second news item (same thing with the Firebase on.(child_changed) function). If I comment it out, all of the news items get updated.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `getElementsByClassName` returns a so-called *live* list of nodes.  When you remove the `unread-true` class, the element is also removed from `to_read`.

Say you start with 4 items in `to_read`:

```
0. item1
1. item2
2. item3
3. item4
```

In the first iteration of the loop: `i=0`, so you remove `item1`. Since the list is *live*, `item1` is also immediately removed from `to_read`:

```
0. item2
1. item3
2. item4
```

In the second iteration: `i=1`, so you remove `item3`. This again immediately removes is from `to_read`, which becomes:

```
0. item2
1. item4
```

In the next iteration: `i=2`, since the `to_read.length` is now also 2, we exit the loop.

**Solution**

There are many ways to deal with this. I'll give one of the simpler ones, which is to loop over the items in reverse order:

```
    for (var i = to_read.length-1; i >= 0; i--) { 
        news.child(to_read[i].id).update({unread: 'false'});
        // document.getElementById(to_read[i].id).className = 'newsitem unread-false';
        console.log(to_read[i].id);
    }
```

With this code, we'll start at `i=3`. When we remove the `unread-true` class from that element, it is also removed from `to_read` again. But now in the next iteration of the loop, `i=3` and `to_read` still has 2 items, so the loop continues.